# Django, where's prefetched GenericForeignKey?

Tags: django, prefetch

```
qs = Foo.objects.prefetch_related('items', 'content_object')
```

I can see qs[0]._prefetched_objects_cache contains 'items' (which is reverse lookup of foreign key)

But there's no 'content_object' in the _prefetched_objects_cache.

Although doc says prefetch_related works with GenericForeignKey.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

So where is the prefetched content_object stored?

Answer (score 1):

Note [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) say:

> For example, prefetching objects referenced by a GenericForeignKey is only supported if the query is restricted to one ContentType.

As I understand that, `prefetch_related` would work for the following queryset, where all the generic foreign keys point to the `Bar` model.

```
bars = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myapp", model="bars")
qs = Foo.objects.filter(content_type=bars).prefetch_related('items', 'content_object')
```